Does Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality have more "refined" form?
From inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, we can say $f(n)=n+\frac{1}{n},n\in N$ has a minimum value of 2 when $n=\frac{1}{n}$. We also found $f(n)$ tends to be smaller for closer values between $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$.
Now consider Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in integral form:  $(\int fg)^2 \leq (\int f^2)(\int g^2)$, this becomes an equality when $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.
My question is, can we say that $(\int f^2)(\int g^2)$ tends to be smaller for "more linearly dependent" $f$ and $g$? I know linear dependence is a binary property, but suppose we have a measure of this "dependence".
For example, we have $(\int x^5)^2 \leq (\int x^4)(\int x^6)$ and $(\int x^5)^2 \leq (\int x^2)(\int x^8)$, it seems that $(\int x^4)(\int x^6) \leq (\int x^2)(\int x^8)$ because the former is somehow closer to $(\int x^5)^2$.

I think you mean something like this.  Suppose we fix $f$ and $\int fg$, where $f$ and $g$ are both square-integrable.  Thus we can write $g = \alpha f + h$ where $\alpha = (\int fg)/(\int f^2)$ and $\int f h = 0$, and we have $\int g^2 = \alpha^2 \int f^2 + \int h^2$.  Smaller values of $\int h^2$ mean $g$ is closer to being a multiple of $f$, and result in smaller values of $\int g^2$.

Thanks for providing this measure of dependency. But back to the example in my question, I'm still confused. x^5 can be x^2 * x^3 or x^1 * x^4, can we use your measure to prove x^2 * x^3 is closer in terms of the linear dependency to x^5?
